# How can I get the LiveCharts LabelPoint value?

Tags: wpf, livecharts

I'm trying to customize the default tooltip starting with the example [here](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Tooltips%20and%20Legends).

Here's the relevant xaml:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Points}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type wpf:DataPointViewModel}">
            <Grid Margin="2">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Stroke="{Binding Series.Stroke}" Fill="{Binding Series.Fill}"
                           Height="15" Width="15"></Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ChartPoint.SeriesView.LabelPoint}" 
                           Margin="5 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding ChartPoint.X}"
```

And that gives me

[image]

Looking to get the string value, and not the .ToString() result. In this case it should be "Pressure Control" I can't seem to find that property or any examples. How can I retrieve this value?

Edit - here's the code that sets the LabelPoint:

```cs
var series = new ScatterSeries
{
    MinPointShapeDiameter = 5,
    MaxPointShapeDiameter = 100,
    DataLabels = true,
    LabelPoint = p => mg.Label   // mg is a POCO, and mg.Label is "Pressure Control" for this series.
};
```

So somehow LiveCharts is displaying this LabelPoint as the label automatically, and I'd like to get the same value in my tooltip.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking a question on SO. Saying "in this case it should be 'Pressure Control'" doesn make much sense given the sample code you have (not) proviced.

Comment: @mm8 - thanks for the comment. I assumed that would be clear given the screenshot, but I assumed. Hopefully the added code corrects that.

Comment: It looks like LabelPoint is Func<ChartPoint, string> and the binding will show you exactly that. It is not string property. They are not using LabelPoint in the examples to which you provided link. They use this Binding ChartPoint.Instance.(local:CustomerVm.Name) to customise the tooltip. Maybe if you do not use that xaml code and that binding and only update LabelPoint then you would be able to somehow alter the default label. Or bind to properties like they do.